# How to check a single radio button using jquery/java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, netsuite

I would like to check only one radio button but in my code both radio buttons get selected.
Here is my code its in netsuite.

```
<input value="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>"  type="radio"    name="service_level"  onclick="getAddonFromNetsuite(<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>, '<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','pricelevel5')%>');"><label for="radio-2-1"></label>
<input value="INPUT"  type="radio" id="radio-2-2" name="service_level_1"  onclick="getAddonFromNetsuite(<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>, '<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','pricelevel5')%>');"/><label for="radio-2-2"></label>
```

here is the link of the site http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/act

Comment: Please provide more HTML / JS.. where is the code that is checking both items?

Comment: Firstly, looks like you should use same name attribute for both radios, isn't it?! You have to post relevant code in question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the "name" of the radios be same for all.

```
<input value="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>"  type="radio"    name="service_level"  onclick="getAddonFromNetsuite(<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>, '<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','pricelevel5')%>');"><label for="radio-2-1"></label>
<input value="INPUT"  type="radio" id="radio-2-2" name="service_level"  onclick="getAddonFromNetsuite(<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','internalid')%>, '<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','pricelevel5')%>');"/><label for="radio-2-2"></label>
```

Comment: Please test once more.